# Wicket external link

Tags: hyperlink, wicket

I am using an external link which points to a url which is generated after a user fills in a form

I am using a IModel as the model for the external link, sadly it looks like the model does not update the external links url, has anyone had an issue like this before.

My code

model declaration:

```
IModel<String> url;
```

model assignment within an onsubmit ajax link

```
 url = getUrl(params);
```

declaration of external link:

```
 ExternalLink el = new ExternalLink("el", url);
```

Comment: I assume you're changing the 'url' variable, after you've passed its value to the ExternalLink constructor. This way the link will not have the most current params in its model. If this is not the case, show us how #getUrl() works.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the Model, but you should just overwrite the ModelObject.

try

```
url.setObject(/*get input as string from anywhere);
```

Also, make sure you added the ExternalLink or a Parent of ExternalLink to the AjaxRequestTarget.